# Azure publishing profile to deploy to multiple cloud services at once

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to deploy one Azure application package (`.cspkg`) with `N` different configuration files(`.cscfg`) to the cloud.

I know that Visual Studio makes it easy to publish packages with "publish profiles" (`.azurePubxml`) however I still could not figure out how can I automate deployment of N cloud services all using same app package.

Is it possible? I don't want to go down Powershell route as it's tedious to write a good script and I don't want to mess with uploading cspkg blob etc. Is there an easier way to deploy an app with different `cscfg`s at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish-AzureServiceProject does most of the work for you - but you would need to write your own script to swap out the correct configuration file.